# Using currently invalid input data for prediction purposes

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, prediction, forecasting

Let's say we have some data (input) with which we want to predict some output. If the possible values that a specific input can take has changed over time, is it still appropriate to use all of the data?

Let me try to clarify with an example. Suppose that one of the inputs is a categorical variable that has the unique values `[A, B, C]` in the data, but we know for a fact that in the current setting in which we will ultimately make predictions, only the values `[A, B]` are possible.

Would it still be appropriate to use all of the data, or should all of the observations that include a `C` be excluded?

Comment: It depends. If the rest of the input variables provide rich information to the model, then your model will learn something useful even from those 'C' data. If this categorical variable is the strongest predictor, then probably you would need to train the model only on the 'A' and 'B' cases.

Comment: @Stergios Thanks for the answer. I'm having a hard time getting my head around this from a theoretical standpoint, but so what you're saying is that the 'invalid' observations are not necessarily garbage.

Comment: @Yahya I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe I've been unclear, but anyway, the 'change' is in the set of possible values. So the question is if that change renders the use of 'old' data inappropriate.

Comment: Almost, except that you can assume that C will never be a possible input in future predictions. When present in the historical data, however, C has explanatory power.

Comment: @Yahya Let's assume that there is only one target, and that it's a binary target.

Comment: @Yahya Thanks! That has been my intuition all along, but I was struggling when trying to justify it theoretically. Your last comment made it much more clear. Cheers. (Feel free to add that as an answer so we can mark it complete).

Comment: Yes, they are not necessarily garbage. For example, decision tree-based models may find this extra information useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `C` does not uniquely map to the Target variable, but rather it shares some target variables with `A` or/and `B`. In this case, leaving `C` in the dataset, knowing that it'll definitely not occur in the future input (i.e. where you predict for unseen inputs), will adjust the hypothesis of the model (and that depends on the model, linear models are more prone to this) and the final hypothesis will consequently be based on redundant information.

In simple terms: *In-Sample* does not represent the *Out-of-Sample*, so it will overfit and won't generalize!.